# CPanel 11 Auto Login?

Tags: authentication, cpanel

Does anyone know if there's a way to automatically login to CPanel 11 and then redirecting to somewhere else? I've tried everything, some things work better than others, for example, using and iFrame I can achieve this but only in Firefox. Neither XMLHttpRequest nor Curl work. The only solution is recreating the form and autosubmitting it once the page loads, but this doesn't work for me as I don't want to go to the CPanel once logged in, I want to go to a menu of my own where I have  a link that points to CPanel.
Thanks in advance,

D

Comment: Redirecting to somewhere else where? Do you mean login into cPanel and for instance redirect to the emails account list still in cPanel?

Answer (score 4):

try this, not sure if it works:

```
POST: http://cpanelurl/login/

parameters: 
login_theme=cpanel&user=yourusername&pass=yourpassword&goto_uri=yoururl

example:
POST to: http://cpanel.spacenets.com/login/
parameters: login_theme=cpanel&user=bluebl&pass=23dff&goto_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements required to make this functionality are –

```
    Server/WHM Username
    Cpanel account Username
    Server login URL
    Server accesshash key
```

And for Accesshash key , New or already generated Access key can get from here:-
WHM > Remote Access Key area and the Access Key located there.
or it should be at this path “/usr/local/cpanel/bin/realmkaccesshash

```
$query = "https://$server_login_link:2087/json-api/create_user_session?
api.version=1&user=$cpanel_user&service=cpaneld";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$header[0] = "Authorization: WHM $whmusername:" . 
preg_replace("'(\r|\n)'","",$hash);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

if ($result == false) {
   // your error log
}
if($result){
   $decoded_response = json_decode( $result, true );
   if(isset($decoded_response['data']) && !empty($decoded_response['data']))
    {
        $url = $decoded_response['data']['url'];
       return $url;        
   }

}
```

When you will open the returned URL in a new tab then cpanel is already logged in for that.